# Microsoft Discounts for University Alumni?

Tags: license

I've been tempted to enroll in a .5 credit hour class at a local community college so I could qualify for Microsoft's student discounts, but I was curious if anyone is aware of any discounts for Alumni of MS-partnered schools?  I've still got a valid student ID :-D

Answer (score 4):

Another option to getting large amounts of software at a cheap cost is buying a TechNet subscription.  TechNet provides you with access to many Microsoft products, all fully licensed, but with some additional restrictions.  $349 for the first year, and $249 for renewals.

This may end up being cheaper than enrolling at your college, I don't know what the tuition is there.  Regardless, it pays for itself if you use it enough.

Comment: It's a good idea; I actually already have a TechNet subscription and have considered extending it, but was hoping to get Visual Studio too--then again the VS2010 beta is meeting my needs and I can always fall back to Express if needed.

Comment: The TechNet is a great option if you want many pieces of software.

Comment: Far cheaper than class.

Answer (score 2):

[Microsoft Dreamspark](https://downloads.channel8.msdn.com/) and [MSDN Academic Alliance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/academic/default.aspx) are the two main student discounts available from Microsoft.

Comment: Yeah, Dreamspark and the Ultimate Steal are the two programs I'd like to get into.  Just was hopeful I wouldn't have to take a BS class just to save a couple grand.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're entitled to student discounts just because you were once in a school.

Just buy the student edition anyway, most retailers don't care. Just don't use it for profit.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose if you have your id, you could get some discounts, but you're borderline cheating the system.  Some schools require more credits or even a computer related class to access things like the MSDN alliance and further student software programs.

Also, there is the option of being.....you know....legit and buying the normal version.

Comment: The Microsoft legalese requires me to be an active student enrolled in .5 credit hours--if they find out I'm not then they'll bill me the difference.  I'm not willing to pay the retail for most of their offered products--I don't think they're worth the asking price.